# Setting confirmation on button click

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have designed this app for android and users want me to add a confirmation pop up for the button action to continue. Something like if `Yes` is clicked then the action continues , but if `No` is clicked the process breaks . I have read through the Web and see that a `dialog` is used for this. Can someone explain probably with a **sample code** how this works.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at sample code below.in this sample if you are calling it from activity pass "this" in showDialog context parameter,If your are showing that dialog in fragment pass getActivity() instead of context

```
public void showDialog(Context context,String title,String msg){

  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  // set title
  alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
  // set dialog message
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Confirm")
    .setMessage("Do you really want to do Perform this Action?")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }})
     .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
```